# Why are INSERTS into my MySQL table taking so long

Tags: mysql, optimization

I am building a MySQL accounts database. I have a routine which imports the entire database from a json file. The routine runs inside a single transaction,
drops all the records from every table, calls:

```
ALTER TABLE <tablename> AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

on each table, then loads the tables from data using INSERT statements like

```
INSERT INTO Journal (idJournal, DocumentId, AccountId, Memo, JournalNum,
 Amount, Outstanding, Cleared, NameAddressId) 
 VALUES (11423, 4454, 14, 'Deposit', 1, 53.33, 53.33, 'X', 292)
```

(Note that the tables are loaded in the right order, so the related records already exist).

I am finding the insert statements are taking a long time (some up to 70 msec), especially compared with loading the same data from a mysqldump.

Is there anything I can do to speed this up (other than using mysqldump instead, which I don't want to do because I want the backup data to be in json format)?

Table definition:

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts`.`Journal` (
    `idJournal` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `DocumentId` INT NOT NULL,
    `AccountId` INT NOT NULL,
    `Memo` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
    `JournalNum` INT NOT NULL,
    `Amount` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
    `Outstanding` DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `Cleared` CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    `NameAddressId` INT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`idJournal`),
    INDEX `fk_Journal_Document1_idx` (`DocumentId` ASC),
    INDEX `fk_Journal_Account1_idx` (`AccountId` ASC),
    UNIQUE INDEX `Document_Num` (`DocumentId` ASC, `JournalNum` ASC),
    INDEX `fk_Journal_NameAddress1_idx` (`NameAddressId` ASC),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Journal_Document1`
   FOREIGN KEY (`DocumentId`)
   REFERENCES `accounts`.`Document` (`idDocument`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Journal_Account1`
   FOREIGN KEY (`AccountId`)
   REFERENCES `accounts`.`Account` (`idAccount`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_Journal_NameAddress1`
   FOREIGN KEY (`NameAddressId`)
   REFERENCES `accounts`.`NameAddress` (`idNameAddress`)
   ON DELETE NO ACTION
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
  ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: So you issue a separate insert query for each line of the json file?

Comment: I can't help but wonder why anyone would ever *think* of attempting such a task.  MySQL has plenty of ready-to-go [backup strategies](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/backup-methods.html)—why roll your own?!

Comment: Because I am not strictly backing up, more allowing for export and import of data to json format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing multiple inserts, it's more performant to insert multiple lines in a single statement, especially if you have a lot of secondary indexes:

```
INSERT INTO Journal (idJournal, DocumentId, AccountId, Memo, JournalNum,
  Amount, Outstanding, Cleared, NameAddressId) 
VALUES (11423, 4454, 14, 'Deposit', 1, 53.33, 53.33, 'X', 292),
       (11424, 4455, 15, 'Deposit', 1, 23.33, 23.33, 'X', 293),
       ...
```

That way, the indexes are only updated once (at the end of the statement), rather than after each insert.

If your database grows beyond 1GB, you're going to have problems because you'll reach the limit of [`max_allowed_packet`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet). In that case, you may have to break it up into multiple queries.

When you say "drops all the records", I hope you mean drop table or truncate table rather than actually deleting all the records.

Comment: There are issues - the MySql documentation says TRUNCATE TABLE deletes one row at a time if there are foreign keys (which there are). As for multiple inserts, this does not allow for fields which may be missing in some of the records and not others.

Comment: You can name all columns in the INSERT and use `NULL` or `DEFAULT` as needed for the value. I'm glad you're reading the docs and see that there are more peformant ways than using `DELETE` to clear a table.

Comment: What happens if I rollback the transaction halfway through (e.g. due to invalid input data)? Will everything be as it was before, or are TRUNCATE 9or DROP, if I use that) not transaction friendly? The documentation on TRUNCATE is a bit unclear on this point.

Comment: You cannot rollback a DROP or TRUNCATE because they perform an [implicit commit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/implicit-commit.html) before and after.

Comment: OK, so it's back to my original code which DELETEs all the records. What about the ALTER TABLE - is that transaction friendly?

Answer (score 0):

This works with "no" interruption of usage of the table:

1. `CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;`
2. Load `new` by batched INSERTs (or whatever).
3. `RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;` -- Instantaneous and atomic
4. `DROP TABLE old;`

No TRUNCATE, no AUTO_INCREMENT=1

Comment: Sounds interesting! What happens if I rollback the transaction after some of the tables have been processed, but not others? Will the database be in the same state it was at the start?

Comment: That's a point.  I left out some details: Add `BEGIN` ... `COMMIT` around step 2, plus code to check for errors and `ROLLBACK` (instead of `COMMIT`) when appropriate.  Note that such a transaction _cannot_ include `CREATE`, `RENAME` or `DROP`, so only step 2 can have the begin...commit.

Comment: I guess I could load all the data into parallel tables, commit, then do a single RENAME to rename them all, followed by a series of drops. I would have to put some DROP IF EXIST statements at the start, in case there was a power cut before the drops completed. BTW, what happens if there is a power cut while the "instantaneous" rename is happening?

Comment: Be careful not to have a huge amount of activity inside one BEGIN..COMMIT.  Since you have a fallback (by reloading), there is little use for any transactional integrity during the loading.

Comment: Yes, there is a chance of trouble during the RENAME.  It is slim, and I suspect there would be tmp tables left around.  Rerunning the load script might stumble over extra/missing tables and need some fixing by hand.  All the tables can (should) be renamed in a single RENAME.  What you have now is _more_ vulnerable to a power failure.

Comment: Why is it vulnerable to a power failure at all? Everything is inside a single transaction, and this should be automatically rolled back, shouldn't it?